# For how long would I need to use a lens hood during the day and in how many shots

Tags: lens-hood

### Question

I was wondering if it is worth it carrying a lens hood around. I read a few articles ([1](https://digital-photography-school.com/lens-hoods-what-are-they-really-for-and-do-you-need-them/), [2](https://www.theschoolofphotography.com/tutorials/camera-lens-hoods), [3](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Canon-Lenses/Lens-Hoods.aspx)) and now I know what is a lens hood and how it works, but I do not know for how long would I need to have one on my lens during the day and how often would it make a difference in my photos.

### Equipment

Camera: `Canon EOS 2000D`

Lens: `Canon Zoom Lens EF-S 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6 IS II`

Polarizing Filter (if needed): `K&F Concept C-Series HMC CPL 58mm`

Comment: We can't answer this as it depends entirely on what and where you're shooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to use lens hood is to stop stray light to come onto your lens and make flare (and decrease the contrast). Also hood can play the role of bumper when lens hit some object.

I personally put it on the lenses very long time and keep it there. The only rare occasions when I remove it is when I change the filter on the lens. But after change I put it on back. Of course this increase a bit the size of the lens but this do not bother me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is largely up to the individual photographer and situation. Personally, if the lens came with a hood, I pretty much just leave it on, because it does provide a little extra protection for the front element. There are exceptions, though, like if it would interfere with positioning (e.g. with a macro lens shooting extremely close to something - most non-macro lenses have a minimum focusing distance that is much farther out), or if the hood would cast a shadow across the image due to strong directional lighting, or if I artistically decide I actually want to encourage lens flare or other effects that a hood is designed to minimize.